# How To Make TextBox Read Only With Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have been given an old project that was created in asp, and I need to make one of the textboxes readonly (because it is populated by a dropdown box and should not allow any free text entries).  This would be cut and dry to set the attribute of ReadOnly = "True" . . .except there seems to be some sort of js function on keppress that is preventing the read only attribute from working.  I have very little experience and knowledge in JS and so I am lost as to how to resolve - what should be an easy change.

I have tried adding the ReadOnly Attribute to True, within the html, but something odd happened.  When a user types in the box, the text appears in the box, but they can not delete it. So, that tells me it is partially working, but something else is going on.

I then looked at the source code from the actual page view (in browser) and that's where I saw the kepress event being triggered . . (onkeypress="return TheControl.RY(this, event);").  Because that did not show on my ascx file.

In short . . the ReadOnly attribute is failing because something onkeypress is triggering . . .  (a) I don't fully understand what the JS is doing, or how to make the box read only.

This is the code for the text box in the .ascx file

```
 <span class="ComposeHeaderValue">
                <asp:TextBox runat="server"     ID="ToTextBox" TabIndex="1" ReadOnly="true" />
            </span>
```

But when I view source code from the browser, this is the html:

```
 <span class="ComposeHeaderValue">
                <input name="TheControl$ToTextBox" type="text" readonly="readonly" id="TheControl_ToTextBox" tabindex="1" onkeypress="return TheControl.RY(this, event);" />
            </span>
```

I don't have any experience with JS, but it looks like it's calling an event (RY) onkeypress . . so I found something called RY in one of the js files and this is what it has

```
  RY: function Rockliffe_MailSite_Web_UI_Client_ComposeControl_ComposeControl$RY(lV, nd) {
    this.lR('ComposeControl', 'RY', lV.id + ',' + nd);
    if (!this.na) {
        return true;
    }
    return this.pg.Cu(lV, nd);


 },
```

And I have no idea what's happening in this code.  I attempted to add the attribute change within the JS RY . . . but that didn't work.  This is what I tried:

```
    RY: function  Rockliffe_MailSite_Web_UI_Client_ComposeControl_ComposeControl$RY(lV, nd) {
    this.lR('ComposeControl', 'RY', lV.id + ',' + nd);
    if (!this.na) {
        return true;
    }
    return this.pg.Cu(lV, nd);

    document.getElementById('ToTextBox').readOnly = true;
 },
```

If I can't find a way to make the textbox ReadOnly . . because of the keypress event, how do I disable the keypress event from happening? In theory, if the textbox is readonly, there will never be a keypress event??

---

Working with the solution Archer Provided . . . .  this is my updated code that is still not working properly

```
        <div class="ComposeHeaderLine">
            <WebUtils:IconButton runat="server" id="ToComposeButton" style="float:left"/>
            <span class="ComposeHeaderValue">
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="ToTextBox" TabIndex="1" ReadOnly ="true" />
            </span>
        </div>
```

And at the very bottom of the page I added the following

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function onKeyPress(textbox, event) {
textbox.value += event.key;
}

document.getElementById("ToTextBox").removeAttribute("onkeypress");
</script>
```

Not sure if I have configured the JS correctly ????

---

New Edit

Okay, so . . . in my asp code, the textbox does NOT have any onkeypress event.  But, when I view sourcecode on the web browser, it does show an onkeypress event. . . and I am wondering if there is something with this.

```
"return TheControl.RY(this, event);"

<input name="TheControl$ToTextBox" type="text" readonly="readonly"   id="TheControl_ToTextBox" tabindex="1" onkeypress="return TheControl.RY(this,  event);" />
```

I have two questions.  Using the example Archer provided . . .

1. The name of his function is onKeyPress.   So, should I rename my function to "return TheControl.RY(this, event);"  ???
2. Is the getElement line of code supposed to be within the brackets or after?  Archer shows it after . .. but I don't understand why it's not within the brackets?

Comment: did you try disabled ?

Comment: FYI, your `document.getElementById('ToTextBox').readOnly = true;` will never execute as it comes _after_ the `return` statement.

Comment: @WilliamBright - I had not yet tried disabled, as I had read that disabled will not carry the value of the textbox over, if the form saves data to the table?  Is that correct?

Comment: @WilliamBright and ExecChef: One can't use `disabled`, as if, the value will never be sent to the server on submit. And it obviously should as it's be set using a drop down box.

Comment: @LGSon - I tried moving the statement up before the return, and that did not work.  That got me thinking.  Am I looking at the right js code?  I also added an alert - and that did not trigger on keypress either.  I am lost.  "onkeypress="return TheControl.RY(this, event)"   Am I looking at the right js code . . RY?

Comment: I don't believe that it is a keypress event that's causing you a problem.  Can you tell us if the cursor flashes in the textbox when it has focus?

Comment: @Acher Yes, the cursor flashes in the textbox when it has the focus even when Readonly attribute is set to true.  The odd part is that you can type in the box, but you cannot delete or backspace when this attribute is set to true.  I tested another textbox that does not have an event on keypress, and the readonly attribute works perfectly when set to true.  That's why I am inclined to believe there is something that is undoing the readonly - that is associated to the kepress event

Comment: Thanks for the extra info.  I've put something together that may help and posted it below.

Comment: Save value from dropdown in `asp:HiddenField` and visualize in `asp:label`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't delete or backspace then that does sound like a keypress handler is updating the value, but ignoring the `readonly` attribute.  I wouldn't expect the cursor to flash if the readonly attribute is there, but I have no idea what the 3rd party code is doing.

However, you can remove the keypress handler which may or may not conflict with some of the 3rd party code.  It's the simplest plausible solution that doesn't involve ripping apart someone else's library.

Here's an example of 2 text boxes, where I've removed the keypress handler from one of them with Javascript.

```js
function onKeyPress(textbox, event) {
  textbox.value += event.key;
}

// remove the event handler from textbox2
document.getElementById("textbox2").removeAttribute("onkeypress");
```

```html
<input id="textbox1" type="text" readonly="readonly" onkeypress="onKeyPress(this, event)" placeholder="You can type in me" />
<br /><br />
<input id="textbox2" type="text" readonly="readonly" onkeypress="onKeyPress(this, event)" placeholder="You can't type in me" />
```

You just need that one line of Javascript added to your page (and modify the ID to suit).

The only caveat is that the line of code that removes the keypress event handler *must* take place after the handler has been added by the 3rd party code.  Ideally, just stick it in a script tag at the very bottom of the body.

Comment: Archer - I have made the changes . .but something is not right.  Nothing has changed.  I am probably not configuring the JS code properly?  I have updated my original question to show how I implemented your code (most likely incorrectly)

Comment: Don't add the `onKeyPress()` function - that was just to demonstrate before and after.  Just add the 1 line below the comment about removing the handler.  If still nothing has changed then it's due to the 3rd party code, so there's very little anyone can do to help.  Can you not just remove whatever that is?

Comment: Thanks for all of your help.  I removed the onkeypress().  Doing this, generates an error in the third party code, but does not make the textbox readonly.  Possibly the key is to add the 'remove attribute' js at the very very end, after the closing body tag.  But, the problem is that the third party code is somewhat cryped . . and the site builds on the fly, so there is no actual closing body tag.   We have run out of things to try, and so they have decided to contact the vendor. . .thank you all for your help.